# Android Volley library gives timeout error with cellular data connection

Tags: java, android, android-volley

im using android volley library for my application and when im using wifi its working but it seems to have problem with cellular data connection. in some phones(LG G3 Android 6,Meizu android 5.1) with cellular data it doesnt work and gives timeout error but in (HTC desire 816 android 4.4, lg g3 android 5.0) again its working

what is the problem?

logcat:

```
D/ERROR: error => com.android.volley.TimeoutError
```

code:

```
showLoadingDialog();
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject jobjHRM = jobj.getJSONObject("HRM");
                    int status = jobjHRM.getInt("StatusCode");
                    if (status == 200) {
                        if (jobj.getJSONObject("Data").getBoolean("result") == true) {
                            login_info_editor.putInt("id", jobj.getJSONObject("Data").getInt("id"));
                            login_info_editor.putString("username", txtlayoutid.getEditText().getText().toString());
                                login_info_editor.putString("password", txtlayoutpass.getEditText().getText().toString());
                            login_info_editor.putBoolean("loged", true);
                            login_info_editor.commit();
                            checkversion();
                        } else {
                            login_info_editor.clear();
                            login_info_editor.commit();
                            txtlayoutid.requestFocus();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "نام کاربری یا کلمه ی عبور اشتباه است", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            txtlayoutid.startAnimation(shake);
                            txtlayoutpass.startAnimation(shake);
                            hideLoadingDialog();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ارور " + status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    hideLoadingDialog();
                    Log.d("ERROR", "error => " + error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(xxxxxx);
            params.put(xxxxxx);
            params.put(xxxxxx);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to configure retry policy. Give a large timeout and try,

```
int socketTimeout = 30000; // 30 seconds. You can change it
RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,                 
DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,     
DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

postRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
```

Comment: Try different values for `socketTimeout`

Comment: Because at that time `postRequest` is null. Add it just before `AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest)`

Comment: Awesome. Happy coding :)