# StringRequest always going to onErrorResponse

Tags: android, android-volley

The code below is my string request, to which I have to send a param token to get data (from fb in this case).

Im pretty sure my problem is in the url, but I tried everything I could come up with.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/login";
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // response
                        Log.d("Response", response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error
                        System.out.println("Request onErrorResponse");
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("token", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(postRequest);
    }
```

The error im getting is:

```
 04-02 01:51:37.755 6096-6096/com.example.nicolas.narau W/System.err: com.android.volley.TimeoutError
04-02 01:51:37.755 6096-6096/com.example.nicolas.narau W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:141)
04-02 01:51:37.755 6096-6096/com.example.nicolas.narau W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
04-02 01:51:45.103 6096-6151/com.example.nicolas.narau I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

I have a high retrypolicy, I dont know why I'm not getting response, since my API works fine in postman

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Edited with the complete error

Comment: Error is that volley library api is giving time out error.

Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092911/android-volley-library-gives-timeout-error-in-cellular-data-connection